# waitMsg message in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, downtime

I'm using

```
Ext.getCmp('my_form').submit(
{
  url: 'http://does-not-respond.onion/',
  method : 'POST',
  waitMsg : 'Please wait...',
  timeout: 5,
  params :
  {
```

The "Please wait" window doesn't disappear. How I can make it disappear and alert a message? I want it to disappear and show error message if the server does not respond, like the internets has gone away.

Comment: Your issue might be related to this bug, for which an override patch was provided:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228970

Comment: The `timeout:` config is in milliseconds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking the `failureType` on form action's failure

```
Ext.getCmp('my_form').submit({
  url     : 'http://does-not-respond.onion/',
  method  : 'POST',
  waitMsg : 'Please Wait...',
  timeout : 5,
  params  : {},
  success : function(){console.log('success...');},
  failure: function(form, action){
                if (action.failureType === Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Error',
                        'Status:'+action.response.status+': '+
                        action.response.statusText);
                }
            }
});
```

refer [Ext.form.action.Action-property-failureType](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-property-failureType)